# Error on creating socket server with socket.io on typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, socket.io

Im new at socket io and im trying to use typescript on the project so i got the error of the image on start the socket server, i already tried to change the import to  `import * as socketIo from 'socket.io'`  but nothing changes, i dont know if is some version issue or im doing something wrong.

the error:
[image: The error]

code:

[image: code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type declaration for socket.io does not contain default export. You can check it in its index.d.ts. It contains the following:

```
export { Socket, ServerOptions, Namespace };
```

That's why to init socket.io server object you need to use the following instruction:

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = new http.Server(app);
const io = new socketio.Server(httpServer);
```